# How to separate 2 complete names with a semicolon when there's no space (and exclude names starting with "Mc"

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm looking to create a regex ot assist to separate full names that sometimes do not have a space.  For example:

```
import re
s = "Bob JonesAlex Smith"
print(re.sub(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)", r"\1; \2", s))
```

This correctly prints "Bob Jones; Alex Smith".

However, when I have names that start with "Mc" like "McMahon", it doesn't work as intended.  Example:

```
import re
s = "Bob McJonesAlex Smith"
print(re.sub(r"([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)", r"\1; \2", s))
```

The above will print "Bob Mc; JonesAlex Smith".

Any regex ideas that can help exclude this pattern?

Comment: Even if you solve the problem with Mc, your approach will also fail with names that don't begin with a capital, as van de Graaff, del Ponto. In general, the problem you have set yourself isn't capable of a good solution.

Comment: Agreed it won't be robust, but it's small enough where I don't have a lot of those other issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have looked over all the dataset and you saw Mc in the starting of some people's name you can try this,

```
([A-Z](Mc)?[a-z]+)([A-Z](Mc)?[a-z]+)
```

"?" is a quantifier which will check its predecessor element 1 or 0 times

Comment: This didn't handle the "Mc" names, but going along with @BoarGules suggestion, I found a workaround that doesn't rely on manually parsing the various scenarios.

Comment: This matches e.g. "DMconald" but not "McDonald".

Answer (score 0):

You can add a negative lookahead to say "don't match Mc".

```py
print(re.sub(r"((?!Mc)[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)", r"\1; \2", s))
```